# When routing "/", console.log does not display any message anywhere in node and express server

Tags: node.js, express

In the code below my problem is that when I do `app.get('/', ...) {...}` the `console.log` inside the curly braces does not work, it seems to work only when I comment the part that point to the directory `'website'`. The thing is in the `/` route, an HTML page is rendered and I want to pass data to that HTML page but nothing works, I would appreciate some insights.

```
    // fake data for now
    projectData = { movie: 'Top Gun', score: '5' };
    
    // Require Express to run server and routes
    const express = require('express');
    // Start up an instance of app
    const app = express();
    
    /* Middleware*/
    const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
    //Here we are configuring express to use body-parser as middle-ware.
    app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
    app.use(bodyParser.json());
    
    // Cors for cross origin allowance
    const cors = require('cors');
    app.use(cors());
    
    // Initialize the main project folder
    app.use(express.static('website'));
    
    // Setup Server
    const port = 8000;
    
    // Make the app listen to the set port
    const server = app.listen(port, listening);
    
    // listening Callback function
    function listening() {
        console.log('Server running on localhost')
        console.log(`Listening to port: ${port}`);
    }
    
    // Messages don't appear inside the get request below
    app.get('/', function (req, res) {
        res.send(projectData);
        console.log('We are here');
    });
    
    // This message show normally for this route
    app.get("/data", function (req, res) {
        res.send(projectData);
        console.log(projectData);
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line of code:

```
app.use(express.static('website'));
```

will automatically handle the `/` route if there is an `index.html` file in the `website` directory.  So, if you don't want `express.static()` to handle the `/` route, then you have multiple options:

1. Remove `index.html` from the `website` directory.
2. Add the `{index: false}` option to `express.static('website', {index: false})` so that it won't match on the `/` route.
3. Move your `app.get("/", ...)` route BEFORE the `express.static()` route so that your custom handler matches the route first.

Comment: Thank you, it worked. I am new to Node and Express and the answer you provided just enlightened me more about how they work. So just to be sure, if "/" returns objects it cannot render an HTML page right?

Comment: @EbillGJ - I do not understand what your previous comment means.  If you're doing `res.send(someObject)`, then that will return JSON, NOT an HTML page, most typically used for an API, not for viewing in a browser.  You need to pick one or the other for each route.  Either return an HTML page (for viewing in a browser) or return JSON (for consumption by code using your API).

Comment: I got it now. Previously I thought that I could somehow return some JSON Data in an HTML page. That is why I came up with the question in the first place. Now it's clear for me that a route returns either an HTML page or some JSON Data. Thanks for your explanations.

Comment: @EbillGJ - It is possible to return an HTML page that has JSON data embedded in it and available to the Javascript in that HTML page.  Or it is possible to combine an HTML template with JSON data and generate HTML that is the HTML visualization of that JSON data.  Both of those would probably be done with an HTML template engine such as EJS, Pug, Nunjucks, Handlebars or [others](https://expressjs.com/en/resources/template-engines.html).

Comment: Sounds interesting, I'll be taking a look at it